# Codeigniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException Unable to connect to database

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have a problem with my ci 4 project. I want to migrate database but cant to connect to database. I need solution to solve this problem.
This is my problem :
Bagazz@Bagazz MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/portfolio-ci4apps
$ php spark migrate

CodeIgniter v4.4.2 Command Line Tool - Server Time: 2023-10-24 07:34:54 UTC+00:00

Running all new migrations...

[CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException]

Unable to connect to the database.
Main connection [MySQLi]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

at SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php:428

Backtrace:
1    SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php:575
CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection()->initialize()

2    SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php:1410
CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection()->query('SHOW TABLES FROM ')

3    SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php:1429
CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection()->listTables()

4    SYSTEMPATH\Database\MigrationRunner.php:764
CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection()->tableExists('migrations')

5    SYSTEMPATH\Database\MigrationRunner.php:168
CodeIgniter\Database\MigrationRunner()->ensureTable()

6    SYSTEMPATH\Commands\Database\Migrate.php:84
CodeIgniter\Database\MigrationRunner()->latest(null)

7    SYSTEMPATH\CLI\Commands.php:65
CodeIgniter\Commands\Database\Migrate()->run([])

8    SYSTEMPATH\CLI\Console.php:46
CodeIgniter\CLI\Commands()->run('migrate', [])

9    ROOTPATH\spark:102
CodeIgniter\CLI\Console()->run()

And this my .env

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENVIRONMENT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

CI_ENVIRONMENT = development

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# APP
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

app.indexPage = ''
# app.baseURL = ''
# If you have trouble with `.`, you could also use `_`.
# app_baseURL = ''
# app.forceGlobalSecureRequests = false
# app.CSPEnabled = false

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

database.tests.hostname = localhost
database.tests.database = portfolio_app.db
database.tests.username = root
database.tests.password =
database.tests.DBDriver = MySQLi
database.tests.DBPrefix =
database.tests.port = 3306

# database.tests.hostname = localhost
# database.tests.database = ci4_test
# database.tests.username = root
# database.tests.password = root
# database.tests.DBDriver = MySQLi
# database.tests.DBPrefix =
# database.tests.port = 3306
```

I need solution please ...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `tests` database group which is primarily used for PHPUnit database tests in the environment `CI_ENVIRONMENT=testing`. Yet, in your current `.env` configuration file, you have it set to `CI_ENVIRONMENT = development`.

If you're **not** running any PHPUnit database tests, and you're currently working in the development environment, configure your database settings in the `.env` file using the `default` database group instead.  I.e:

```
database.default.hostname = ...
database.default.database = ...
database.default.username = ...
database.default.password = ...
database.default.DBDriver = ...
database.default.DBPrefix = ...
database.default.port = ...
```

##### Excerpt from [app/Config/Database.php](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/8b1d9fca3a704aac126f5036dc9b0c70f5a21cb0/app/Config/Database.php#L48)

```php
/**
     * This database connection is used when
     * running PHPUnit database tests.
     */
    public array $tests = [
        'DSN'         => '',
        'hostname'    => '127.0.0.1',
        'username'    => '',
        'password'    => '',
        // ...
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Ensure that we always set the database group to 'tests' if
        // we are currently running an automated test suite, so that
        // we don't overwrite live data on accident.
        if (ENVIRONMENT === 'testing') {
            $this->defaultGroup = 'tests';
        }
    }
}
```